# How to use nsExec::Exec in nsis, when calling psql with a script containing accents?

Tags: nsis, psql

I try to execute this script with psql

```
insert into users (id, name) values ('n1', 'marie');
insert into users (id, name) values ('n2', 'kévin');
```

In NSIS 3.03, using

```
nsExec::Exec '"psql.exe" -U postgres -f "script.sql"'
```

only insert the value 'n1', so the one with no accent.

Using `ExecWait` instead of `nsExec::Exec` inserts all the lines, but I don't want the black DOS box to appear ; [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) causes the same issue as `nsExec::Exec`.

What can i do to make `nsExec::Exec` works fine with scripts containing accents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to encode my scripts in UTF-8 instead of Windows-1252 resolves the issue